# What are the disadvantages for downgrade react-native from 0.58 to 0.57

Tags: react-native

i want to downgrade my react-native from 0.58 to 0.57 because of the problem that realm not working on 0.58 and i found solution that if I downgrade my react-native it work on my real device. so my question is what disadvantages or difficulties i could face to downgrade my react-native (if  any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only consequence will be to lose the [new features](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#058) added on 0.58